# "Hey, buddy, got a quarter?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the joke with the sentence "I wouldn't want you to have a cow, man!
Here's a catch-phrase you better learn for your adult years: Hey,buddy, got a quarter?" ?

> Flanders: Calm down, Neddly diddily diddily diddily, doodily. They did
>   their best shodaiddily iddily iddily diddily diddily. Gotta be nice,
>   hostidididildilidilly... aw, hell-diddly-ding-dong crap! Can't you
>   morons do anything right?! [everyone gasps]
>
> Marge: Ned! We meant well, and everyone here tried their best.
>
> Flanders: Well, my family and I can't live in good intentions, Marge!
>   Oh, your family's out of control, but we can't blame you, because you
>   have good intentions!
>
> Bart: Hey! Back off, man!
>
> Flanders: Ooh, okay, dude! **I wouldn't want you to have a cow, man!
>   Here's a catch-phrase you better learn for your adult years:** **"Hey,
>   buddy, got a quarter?"** [everyone gasps]
>
> Bart: I am shocked and appalled.

http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Hurricane_Neddy/Quotes

Comment: I think the original may have a transcription error; it should read "my family and I can't live *on* good intentions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a slightly meta reference to Bart Simpson's catchphrase "Don't have a cow, man!". "Hey, buddy, got a quarter?" is something a beggar might say. The insult/joke here is that Ned's saying that Bart will grow up to be a beggar and that he should start practicing now.

This is certainly a totally inappropriate and rude thing to say to a child, but everyone is much more shocked because Ned is usually such a nice person.